# How should I set this property correctly in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an interface:

```ts
export interface ItemResponse {
  get: Array<Item>;
  sent: Array<Item>;
}
```

I have some code in the component:

```ts
itemData: ItemResponse;

ngOnInit() {
  this.getItems();
}

getItems(){
  this.itemService.getAllItem().subscribe(data => {
    this.itemData = data;
  });
}
```

The template part:

```html
<item-table [data]="itemData.get"></item-table>
```

I need to use an angular material table several times, so I created a component for that. A want to pass the dataSource, but i get the next error:

```
ItemComponent.html:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ItemComponent.html:11)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:30537)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:29933)
    at callViewAction (core.js:30174)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:30116)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:29939)
    at callViewAction (core.js:30174)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:30137)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:29934)
    at callViewAction (core.js:30174)
```

How should I declare this property? I tried many ways, for example:

```ts
itemData = {get: [], sent:[]} as ItemResponse;
```

In this case, the `itemData.get` wasn't undefined, but it was empty.

Do you have any idea, what should I do with this? Sorry for grammatical mistakes, English is not my first language.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `getItems()` performs an async operation and **`itemData` is `undefined` until the subscription returns a value**.

You need to either use [`async pipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) or a *boolean flag* (such as `isLoaded`) to wait until the subscription is completed.

For `async` pipe, you can do as following:

```
getItems(){
    this.itemData = this.itemService.getAllItem();
}
```

And in the template

```
<item-table [data]="(itemData | async).get"></item-table>
```

---

Or if you want to use a boolean flag:

```
isLoaded = false;

getItems(){
    this.itemService.getAllItem().subscribe(data => {
       this.isLoaded = true;
       this.itemData = data;
    });
}
```

And in the template:

```
<item-table [data]="itemData.get" *ngIf="isLoaded"></item-table>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use async pipe?

```
// Component
itemData$: Observable<ItemResponse>;

ngOnInit() {
 this.itemData$ = this.getItems();
}

getItems(){
return this.itemService.getAllItem();
}
```

in Temlpate

```
<item-table [data]="(itemData$ | async)?.get"></item-table>
```

Or if you don't want to use async pipe
modify your component to this

```
<item-table *ngIf="itemData" [data]="itemData.get"></item-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and works as intended.

The issue is, before your async call returns, `itemData` is undefined, therefore there's an error in the template when it tries to evaluate `itemData.get`

What I'll suggest is using the safe navigator also known as optional chaining [MDN](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining):

```html
<item-table [data]="itemData?.get"></item-table>
```

This will prevent the error as it will only attempt to get the `get` property if `itemData` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You should use RxJS but map the data inside the component to the `get` property.

```js
@Component({...})
export const Class {
  items$: Observable<Item[]>;

  constructor (private itemService: ItemService) {
    this.items$ = this.itemService.getAllItems().pipe(pluck('get'));
  }
}
```

and in your template you won't need to access the property after you ran the async pipe

```html
<item-table [data]="items$ | async"></item-table>
```